# Is it possible to pass only templateUrl in $routeProvider.when()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Can we do something like this?

```
 GuitarApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
    <!-- no controller here -->
  }).
  when('/details/:guitarID', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',
    controller: 'DetailsController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
  });
}]);
```

Beacause the controller that needed there is already added in  tag of HTML, beacause other portion of HTML also want to make of that controller.

Comment: Yes, you can do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the controller in $routeProvider is completely optional.  Just be sure your HTML specifies it.  And be sure that you don't have it in both places!

As comments mentioned, refer to best practices on what is 'best' to do.